# Python temporarily change letter to lower case

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that looks like this:

`separate=[['I','wnet','to','the','mal,'],['and','bouht','a','new','shirt.'],['What','did','you','do','todya?']]`

I'm going to run this through a program which will identify the misspelled words and replace them with the correct word but the list of words in the `Webster Dictionary` that I am using only uses lowercase letters. Can I temporarily change all of the letters to lowercase but then in the end return the original upper and lower case words?

I know about `str.upper()` and `str.lower()` and `set.capitalize`.

It seems like I want to use something like `str.capwords()` but inversely... I want to split the list into words(already done) and then make capital letters lower case.

Comment: When you do the lookup... convert what you're looking up to lowercase then... `if something.lower() in something_else` or whatever... No need to keep around a pre-computed lower cased copy

Comment: You need to include more code if you want an integrated solution, otherwise the answer is pretty much "Yes"

Answer (score 3):

Just use `str.lower`. It will return a new string with lower letter and keep the original string unchanged. So when you loop through the list such as `if string.lower() in adict:`, you do use the lower case to compare and the original string unchanged.

```
>>> a = 'ABC'
>>> a.lower()
'abc'
>>> a
'ABC'
```